# Laptop doesn't turn on after changing RAM

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory

Recently I've changed Ram of my pc from 4gb to 8gb, but it seems that my old PC is only capable of 2gb per slot. Previously i had 2gb(×2) and now I have 8gb(×1). It shows 2gb of Ram on windows 10 so I have switched back to 4gb of memory in two slots (2gb each). And now when i turn it on it just doesn't turn on(or doesn't post) I check that Ram was for perfectly into the slots and was also charging. I don't understand the problem. Can anyone help please.

Comment: 1) It might take quite a bit longer to turn on the first time after changing the RAM as it has to do some tuning. 2) What do you mean by "I check that Ram was ... also charging? Do you mean that the laptop was charging OK, or do you mean something else?

Comment: Have you used proper ESD equipment like a bracelet?

Comment: In addition, I'm wondering if the RAM was handled properly, or that static has damaged it during removal/reseating. Make sure you use a grounded antistatic wristband when messing with memory, and start testing with a single bank. If it doesn't work, try that bank in the other slot, then repeat with the second bank.

Comment: Just a thought, but I had an HP DV6 laptop once, and doubled its ram with compatible sticks, but it wouldn't boot so I reached out to support. they provided me with link to a non-public BIOS that resolved the issue. They had limited memory size in the public version.

Answer (score 0):

If the old RAM sticks are not working any more, it seems like the new RAM
caused a hardware problem.

The problem is likely with the motherboard or with the power supply.

Inspect the motherboard visually for signs of damage or a short.
If you have another power supply, try to see if it helps.

If the above does not help, a repair-shop is indicated.
You should in this case decide whether this old computer
is worth such an investment.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check the compatibility of the RAM in the computer? Can that computer support 8GB RAM sticks?

Many times older machines may require a specific RAM density setup for support. For example, I had an old T61 laptop that supported 8 GB RAM sticks BUT the RAM had to be set up a specific way on the stick for it to work. This RAM wasn't readily available or the cheapest... but it worked.

I'd look up the motherboard/laptop manufacturer to see what size and type RAM is supported.

**EDIT**

Also, make sure you put the same sticks in the same slots. Technically, it shouldn't matter, but I have seen laptops with two slots where two of the same class RAM sticks will work one way but not the other. This is especially true if the two RAM sticks are not identical.

** Edit 2 **

Make sure the RAM sticks are clipped in. Some RAM slots allow sloppy insertion and don't let the stick contacts connect properly.

Comment: The OP can correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like his old memory bars aren't working anymore. I assume those are the correct timing :)